# Upload image, convert to base64 and send to jersey

Tags: web-services, backbone.js, jersey, image-uploading

I'm writing web application where front-end will be written on html, backbone.js and back-end on jersey.
There are many image upload (input type="file") and text data (input type="text") in my html form. I have to upload all of them (image and plain/text) in one request to Jersey server.

I read that I can send image with text data to server in one request only if I convert image to Base64 format.

Is it possible to convert image which is being uploaded via html forms to base64 format and then send all data to jersey?

Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Jersey but I know this will work with other back ends. In this example your model will post to the server image data as `file_name` and `file_data`. You will need to decode the image on the back end. The front end code below is taking advantage of the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader). It will not work in IE < 10.

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  readFile : function (file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (theFile, self) {
      return function (e) {
        self.set({file_name: theFile.name, file_data : e.target.result});
        _.isUndefined(callback) ? null : callback();
      };
    })(file, this);

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
});

var view = Backbone.View({
  //...
  onRender : function () {
    var self = this,
      fileChangeHandler = function (e) {
      var callback = function () {
        self.model.save({}, {});
      };
      var file = e.originalEvent.target.files[0];
      self.model.readFile(file, callback);
    };
    self.$("input[type='file']").change(fileChangeHandler);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you just post multiple text and images in a form to jersey?

html code:

```
<form action="rest/test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="text1" /> <br />
    <input type="file" name="file1" /> <br />
    <input type="text" name="text2" /> <br />
    <input type="file" name="file2" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

jersey code:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {

    public TestResource() {
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public Response create(
            @FormDataParam("text1") String text1,
            @FormDataParam("file1") InputStream file1,
            @FormDataParam("text2") String text2,
            @FormDataParam("file2") InputStream file2) {

        //get your data

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```